# Phpunit and Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, phpunit

I have a PHP project written in PHPUnit using Selenium.

The project is structured as below:
PHPProjectName

- Source Files

  - (doesn't contain anything)
- Selenium Test Files

  - contains all my selenium test php files - extending the class PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
- Include Path

  - c:\program files\PHP
  - c:\program files\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit

I then run start the Selenium server manually by running java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar

The php script to execute all my selenium test php files works fine.

But now I want to use Jenkins as a test management tool to build and execute my PHPunit tests in this folder. I guess the steps are:

- Install Jenkins
- Write a build script for the PHPunit tests
- Execute the build script through Jenkins

Are the steps correct? Has anyone done or know how to set this up?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

I have done this many times with various platforms. Your steps are generally correct and should work, however managing the server is not always so simple. The Selenium RC server gets unstable if left open for too long, so you will have to manage it somehow.

You could set up a second Jenkins job which runs once or twice a day to reset your server. The better option however would be to write a simple test framework which closes any open servers and then launches a new server instance before running the tests. You could also use a cron job to reset the server of course, but if you have Jenkins installed it will be easier to do this via a jenkins job.

The best option of course is to switch to Webdriver, but that could take some work depending on how complex your tests are.

Comment: Thanks for the head up regarding Selenium RC server being unstable.

Comment: Do you have an ANT build script that runs PHPunit script, I'm tring to use the one here http://www.unclecode.com/2012/06/automation-testing-using-integration-of-selenium-phpunit-ant-and-create-reports/ but not having much luck....

Comment: The example at that link looks correct, but I have never used ANT + PHPUnit before, so I don't have any scripts I can share. What is the issue you are having with it?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup to what you describe.  We have Jenkins run a job to restart the Selenium server periodically:

```
#!/bin/bash
# startselenium.sh: Start Selenium up and also start headless screen.
Xvfb :99 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:99 
java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar &
```

Sebastian Bergmann maintains a bunch of templates for using Jenkins with PHP here:
http://jenkins-php.org/

Included is the necessary Ant script to run PHPUnit (which is really simple and just calls PHPUnit):

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true"/>
</target>
```

And the necessary 'phpunit.xml' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    strict="true"
    verbose="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="ProjectName">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/unit/</directory>
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/integration/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="BankAccount"
            charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
        lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>src/bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the selenium plugin in jenkins, then a selenium server will automatically start on jenkins, which will create a hub. Now on the client you have to start a node which connects to this hub.

> *Note*: The jenkins selenium server is always the same version as the selenium plugin from jenkins. So if the selenium plugins name is
>   selenium plugin 3.1.0 then it runs on selenium server 3.1.0.

After installing the jenkins selenium plugin, then you can find a new option for selenium grid, click on it and you will get more informations:

[image]

[image]

Now you have to start a jenkins selenium standalone server like this:

Windows (create a .bat file with the following content and execute it, change relevant parts accordingly):

```
start java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Webdrivers\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Webdrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-<VERSION>.jar -role node -hub http://<YOUR_JENKINS_MACHINE_IP>:<PORT>/grid/register
```

In my case, I used:

```
start java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Webdrivers\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Webdrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar -role node -hub http://172.25.201.100:4444/grid/register
```

Make sure to correct the paths to geckodriver and chromedriver to their actual location.

Now the node should connect to the hub and you can start your tests.

More infos:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2